# Identity 2.0. How to relate a user table in my EF context to Identity AspNetUsers table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am using a boiler-plate VS2013 generated project (Code First, Migrations).

I wish to take the easy route and use all the built-in Identity API for handling of authentication and accounts (register, login all that).

Yet I wish to have a separate user table (let’s call it AppUser) with its own attributes that is not part of Identity because I am implementing my own domain with other relationships (Company => user hierarchy, Documents, etc) this is all admin’d outside of Identity by my custom pages. The AspNetUser would have already registered his account prior to my custom pages wiring him in.

My issue is how do I setup a relationship in the context from AppUser to AspNetUsers.

I thought this would be pretty simple but I am lost.

The only thing I can come up with is to have AppUser have a string called AspNetUser_ID that I would manually join to the AspNetUser table.

This seems pretty brittle and I would prefer it could have a FK constraint.

The other thing I cannot figure out is how to get AspNetUser in my DBContext so it is accessible.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using the boilerplate template, you should be able to find a class file named IdentityModels.cs in the Models folder. There, you can find the ApplicationUser class, to which you can add all the extra properties you want, as with any other Code First entity. This is the entity that maps to the AspNetUsers table. Here you could just add your AppUser class as a navigation property, or maybe, to keep things simple, add the properties from AppUser to ApplicationUser, so you only have one ***User entity to deal with.